# Is there any way to know if click on win8 webview is download or navigation?

Tags: c++, windows, webview

I tried alot , found lots of events are not working in win8 webview element as of now .

Comment: Download and navigation are essentially the same most of the time. You may recognize downloads by `Content-Type` though.

Comment: How do you get the content-type when you  click on href for instance which is of type download in C++ code ?I want to download it if its downloadable or else let it go for navigation?

Comment: By parsing the response header. You can not see the type of content from a link.

Comment: Kindly be more exact ... I don't have code access inside Engine ? I am talking about Application layer which is browser app, and I am using Win8 WebView to Render my webpage and use its provided Api set ?